Google Analytics count for organic search slightly lower than expected
I am tracking a website that was built using SquareSpace and that uses Calendly booking. I inserted the Google measurement ID in Integration section of Calendly.com. I have also implemented cross domain tracking and included the main website and Calendly in the same data stream.
I tested the tracking for Calendly booking and used dummy data, which included the email test@gmail.com. When booking an appointment for testing purposes, I first went to the website via Google Search, so it would count as an organic search. Based on my understanding, test@gmail.com is an invisible email. So Calendly analytics should not count submission for booking, but Google Analytics should count that submission for booking. I did this 4 times on December 4.
So far, I am only seeing 3 counts for organic search on the traffic acquisition report on Google Analytics for the period between December 1 and December 7. What could be the reason?
